# Neo4j Index creation fails

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently getting to know Neo4j and the abilities of a graph database. I also did the movie tutorial that comes with neo4j.

Now I have to work on a big database (~135 GB, 500 mio. nodes, 950 mio. relationships) and want to add an index for a special type of nodes.

This type of nodes, called Transaction, has a property called txid, which is a hash and looks like this: **a56e849c19dfecbe93c9e8bfca8e6df0902775c9ecc2e082eea80436c3d93a51**

I try to add the index with the cypher query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Transaction(txid)
```

It takes a while, throughout the process,

```
:SCHEMA
```

shows

```
Indexes
  ON :Transaction(txid) POPULATING
```

but after a while it turns to FAILED.

I checked the docs, but unfortunately i don't find any mistake why this should not work.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: That's a new one for me, but check the logs.  Note that there is both a `./data/log/console.log` and a `./data/graph.db/messages.log`

Comment: @BrianUnderwood: Thanks for the hint with the log files. It was a problem with the java heap space. Solved it with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530538/java-heap-space-error-neo4j. Index creation worked perfectly fine now!