# neo4j index failed immediately without error

Tags: neo4j

NOTE this is not the same question [Neo4j Index creation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399040/neo4j-index-creation-fails)

We have 2 types of nodes in our DB which both have a string property called `text`. For node `A` this property is not unique and for node `B` this property is unique. (we never explicitly have any cypher code that creates any boundary/unique conditions on anything)

We want to have 2 indexes:

```
create index on :A(text)
create index on :B(text)
```

(i am currently running those cypher queries seperately from the browser interface)

the index on `:B(text)` takes a minute and works fine (4 million nodes), but the index on `:A(text)` (1 million nodes) fails immediately and eventhough i have also tried it with the python driver with the lowest debug level and looked through `/var/log/neo4j/..` i can't find any indication as to why this is failing. Judging by the documentation the fact that `:A(text)` is not unique should not be a problem. Does anyone have hunch where something could be wrong?

EDIT:

- Neo4j Version: 3.4.8
- Longest `:A(text)` string: 17 chars (individual words)
- Longest `:B(text)` string: 53 chars (short phrases)

EDIT: I realize fails immediately can be a bit of a vague term, so here exactly what happens when using the browser interface...

```
create index on :B(text)
```

returns

```
Added 1 index, completed after 1 ms.
```

immediately after

```
:schema
```

returns

```
Indexes
    ON :B(text) POPULATING
```

after a while

```
:schema
```

returns

```
Indexes
    ON :B(text) ONLINE
```

now for A

```
create index on :A(text)
```

returns

```
Added 1 index, completed after 1 ms.
```

immediately after

```
:schema
```

returns

```
Indexes
    ON :B(text) ONLINE
    ON :A(text) FAILED
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. Provide relevant code which you tried. Go through [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to ask a question in SO. Thank You.

Comment: maybe if you read the question you woudl understand i gave you all the information i am capable of since debug mode and neo4j log files (edit) seem to (/edit) have no relevant information. all i know is that the `:A(text)` index fails immediately without error

Comment: Which version of Neo4j? And do you know what the longest string is for this property on :A nodes?

Comment: Neo4j Version 3.4.8.... longest string 17 characters (they are individual words)

Comment: While I'm not sure about the cause, an addition in 3.4.9 may help you diagnose this. From the [3.4.9 changelogs](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.4-changelog#349): `In the case where an index ends up in a failed state, it is now possible to get the cause of the failure from procedure db.indexes. Partly addresses https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12038` And in any case, if you're going to upgrade anyway, you should at least grab the latest 3.4.x version (currently 3.4.14) which may include other indexing fixes.